# Creating a dataframe from a loop from a scraper

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

My dataframe "df" either returns an empty dataframe or just a one or two  column dataframe and not all columns related to the amount of days for which i'm running it for.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.text import OffsetFrom
import re

df=pd.DataFrame()
today=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
end_date=datetime.strptime(today,'%Y-%b-%d')
run_date=datetime.strptime('2019-Jul-1', '%Y-%b-%d')
ref_date=datetime.strptime('2000-May-25', '%Y-%b-%d')

while (run_date-ref_date)<(end_date-ref_date):
  run_date=run_date+timedelta(1)
  url = f'https://www.nasdaq.com/earnings/earnings-calendar.aspx?date={run_date}'
  r =requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
  table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "USMN_EarningsCalendar" })
  if table is None:
    continue
  else:
    rows = table.find_all("tr")
    for i in rows:   
      datas = i.find_all('td')   
      if len(datas)>0:        
        for j in datas:
          a.append(j.text.strip())
          for k in a:
            b.append(re.findall('\(.*?\)',k))
            b = [x for x in b if x != []]
            b_set = set(map(tuple,b))  
            b=list(b_set)
            b.strip('(')
            df[run_date]=b
```

Is this due to the line run_date=run_date+timedelta(1) within the loop?

Comment: Your code returns a None for table after "table = soup.fi....."  Have you considered using [Yahoo Financials](https://pypi.org/project/yahoofinancials/)?

Comment: I'll give it a shot with yahoo financials--thanks for the tip.